# Storing an object reference does not compile when using ? operator for two different object types implementing the same interface

Tags: c#

I just wanted to create a short version of if statement, and I noticed something interesting, please have a look here

```
public class TestClass
{
    public object MyObject { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        //this does not compile
        MyObject = MyBool ? new Object1() : new Object2();

        //this compiles
        MyObject = MyBool ? new Object1() as IObject : new Object2();
    }
}

public interface IObject { }

public class Object1 : IObject
{
}

public class Object2 : IObject
{
}
```

Why the first line in the constructor does not compile if MyObject is just an object, so it can host anything.

Secondly why the second line compiles if only one Object is casted to IObject? How does it know that the second one also is of this type but at the same time it does not see that both of them implement the same interface in the first example?
Changing MyObject to look like this

```
public IObject MyObject { get; set; }
```

Does not make any difference in both cases. This is .Net 4.6 and C# 6 if this makes any different.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Onject1 and Object2 are two different types of objects. They happen to implement the same interface, but the compiler needs them to be of the same type to compile. The moment you cast one to IObject, the compiler knows that the other is also an IObject and can do the conversion.

Comment: Why do they have to be of the same type if the property is of type object? It would make sense if the property was of some type, then I understand that I can't simply assign different type to it. Is it just the way it is in c#?

Comment: Lets be clear (in case I misunderstood your last reply). Object and IObject are two completely different things. If you changed MyObject to be Object instead of IObject then you're correct that you would not need to cast. But that's not what you did. Edit: I stand corrected :) Just tried with object. My original reply is still correct however.

Comment: Im sorry, i didn't notice it, MyObject is object I was testing it and I didn't notice I pasted wrong code (its corrected now). But it does not make any different it behaves exactly the same way. It still won't compile in the first line of the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with the rules associated with the conditional (ternary) operator.

Let's look at the error message.

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Object1' and 'Object2'`

The key word in the error message is **implicit**.

If we look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) reference, it states:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

What is an implicit conversion? It's when we can convert from one type to another without having to cast. We could allow this behaviour by specifying an implicit conversion, like so:

```
public class Object1 : IObject
{
    public static implicit operator Object2 (Object1 o)
    {
        // Somehow convert o into an Object2
        return new Object2();
    }
}
```

This means that the following code is now valid: `Object2 obj = new Object1()`

While it is true that `new Object1()` and `new Object2()` both implement the same interface, they are *not* the same type. You cannot convert an instance of `Object1` to `Object2`, without defining an implicit conversion.

In the second example, the compiler is comparing the two sides of the conditional, and it sees that one is `IObject`, so it checks if there is an implicit conversion between `Object2` and `IObject`, which there is, because `IObject x = new Object2` is a valid statement.

Answer (score 3):

The way that the conditional operator works is that it the type of the expression representing the entire conditional operator is always either the type of the second operand or the type of the third operand.  It will never select a type for the entire operator that is different from both of the operands.  If both operands are the same, the result is that type.  If one can be implicitly converted to the other, then it uses that type.

It will never attempt to use an implicit conversion on both of the operands to convert them both into some new type.

By adding in an explicit conversion on your own, you're now making it so that only one of the operands needs to use an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because Object1 & Object2 are not of type IObject, they only implement from IObject. Additionally this may be because you can implement many interfaces for an object, so an implicit conversion is needed to specify which.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IObject MyObject { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        MyObject = MyBool ? (IObject) new Object2() : new Object1();
    }
}

public interface IObject { }
public interface IOtherObject { }

public class Object1 : IObject, IOtherObject
{
}

public class Object2 : IObject
{
}
```

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They don't *inherit* `IObject`, they *implement* it.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to get better with my terminology, I appreciate the correction.

Comment: this public IObject MyObject { get; set; } is actually this public object MyObject { get; set; }, I've just changed it, and it still does not compile. I always though that I can assign anything to an object as it is base of all classes.

Answer (score 1):

First take a look at this code:

```
String s="blah blah";
Console.WriteLine(s is string);//true
Console.WriteLine(s is object);//true
Console.WriteLine(s is char);//false
Console.WriteLine(s is SomeClass);//false
```

Although `SomeClass` is inherited from `object` class but `String` class doesn't know anything about `SomeClass` type.

According to this, in the `?` mark operator, both values should be in the same type. and when it's not provided, the compiler will gives you an error.

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other
>   [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28(v=vs.100).aspx)